# If para una función

Tags: php

Estoy agregando un registro a mi base de datos mediante una función llamada `insert`. Lo que quiero con el `if` es que si se insertaron correctamente los datos en la base de datos, este muestre un mensaje diciendo que ha sido correcto pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: result in
>   C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\procura\add_user.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\procura\add_user.php
>   on line 9

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
$field = array("nombre"=>$_POST['nombre'],"id_ck"=>$_POST['usuario'],"user_type"=>$_POST['tipo'] );
$tbl = "user";
if (empty($errors)) {
    insert($tbl,$field);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($result)=== '1') {
        $session->msg('s',"Cuenta Creada");
        redirect('usuarios.php', false);
    }           
}
```

Esta es la funcion `insert`:

```
function insert($tblname,$form_data){
    $fields = array_keys($form_data);
    $sql="INSERT INTO ".$tblname."(".implode(',', $fields).")  VALUES('".implode("','", $form_data)."')";

    return db_query($sql);
 }
```

Y esta es la función que uso para conectarme a la base de datos:

```
function db_query($query) {
   $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prueba");
   $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
   return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que la conexión está bien y el resto de cosas están bien. No estás guardando el resultado de llamar a tu función `insert` en ningún lugar.

Tienes que asignarlo a alguna variable para luego comprobar los resultados con `mysqli_affected_rows`:

```
$field = array("nombre"=>$_POST['nombre'],"id_ck"=>$_POST['usuario'],"user_type"=>$_POST['tipo'] );
$tbl = "user";
if (empty($errors)) {
    $result = insert($tbl,$field); // Asignación a $result
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($result)=== '1') {
        $session->msg('s',"Cuenta Creada");
        redirect('usuarios.php', false);
    }           
}
```

Comment: Hice este cambio e igualmente me muestra mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Comment: Y `$result` es null? false? haz un [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: Hize el var_dump y me lanzo que era de tipo bool(true) asi que lo que hice fue en el if poner que si result era true apareceria el mensaje